# Error en envío de correo

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
if (Consulta == "Aprobado") {
  MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
  email.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"));
  email.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
  email.Subject = "Asunto(Correo Prueba)";
  email.Body = "Contenido Prueba";
  email.IsBodyHtml = true;
  email.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = "gmail.com";
  smtp.Port = 465;
  smtp.EnableSsl = false;
  smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
  smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx");

  try {
    smtp.Send(email);
    email.Dispose();
    this.Page.Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript'>window.alert('" +
      "Correo electrónico fue enviado satisfactoriamente" + "');</script>");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    this.Page.Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript'>window.alert('" +
      "Error enviando correo" + "');</script>");
    this.Page.Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript'>window.alert('" +
      ex.Message.ToString() + "');</script>");
  }

}
```

No sé cuál es el error, pero siempre sale "Error enviando correo" y la excepción solo dice "Error al enviar correo". Ya verifique los datos, correos y la contraseña del que envía son correctas, ¿alguien podría indicarme qué está mal?

Comment: Pues en el correo que envía modifqué esta opción Permitir el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras: SÍ pero desconozco que cofiguraciones se deben modificar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

utiliza estos valores para las propiedades de `SmtpClient` usando gmail. el host es incorrecto y debes utilizar el puerto 587 y habilitar ssl

```
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  smtp.Port = 587;
  smtp.EnableSsl = true;
  smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxxxxx");
```

Comment: Gracias!, era eso. Al fin, llevaba dos días en eso, muchas gracias.